# mutually inductive types workaround

Tags: coq

Consider a simple language which has natural numbers, vectors of natural numbers, variables, and some operations like +,- and `nth`. Naively, I would encode it in Coq like this:

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Inductive NExpr: Type :=
| NVarValue: nat -> NExpr
| NConst: nat -> NExpr
| NPlus : NExpr -> NExpr -> NExpr
| NMinus: NExpr -> NExpr -> NExpr
| NNth  : forall n, VExpr n -> NExpr -> NExpr
with
VExpr (n:nat): Type :=
| VVarValue: nat -> VExpr n
| VConst: Vector.t nat n -> VExpr n.
```

Of course, this does not work due to the known limitation producing the error: *"Error: Parameters should be syntactically the same for each inductive type."*

**What would be a correct way to encode such language in Coq?** . Of course, I should be able to write an `eval` function, evaluating these expressions along the lines of https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Imp.html

When evaluating, the dimensionality of vectors is used as follows:

```
match e with
  ...
  | @NNth v i => match Compare_dec.lt_dec (evalNexp st i) n with
                | left p => Vnth (evalNexp st v) p
                | right _ => 0
                end
```

N.B. In this example, `VExpr` does not depend on NExpr, but in future it could, with the addition of constructors some of which may use `NExpr`. Also, I may need to add more types, for example, `ZExpr` for integers.

Comment: Cn you give an example when `VExpr` would depend on `NExpr`? Do I understand your evaluation snippet correctly, then `VExpr` is used to represent values and `NExpr` represents abstract syntax?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between `NVarValue` and `VVarValue`, which both seem to model natural number constants.

Comment: @eponier `NVarValue` and `VVarValue` are lookup functions which take a variable name (represented as a natural number) and return a natural number or a vector respectively.

Comment: @nesreka They both are a syntactic representation of expressions which represent natural numbers and vectors respectively. Example of `NExpr` would be `1+2*3` and the example of `VExpr` would be `[1,2,3]` using more traditional syntax. An example of `VExpr`  which depdens on `NExpr` would be if we add a new constructor to `VExpr`, say `VZeroElement: VExpr n -> NExpr -> VExpr n` which would represent a hypothetical function which takes a vector and replaces an element with given index with 0.

Comment: @krokodil Thanks. Is it feasible to remove the `n:nat` parameter from the second inductive?  You could add is as an argument to the constructors where needed and pattern match on them. You can also move the `forall n:nat, ...` into a `constructor n : ...`

Comment: @krokodil What is the type of the state(s) used to evaluate variables ? In particular, do you have the guarantee that evaluating `VVarValue 10 0` gives a vector of length 10?

Comment: @eponier yes I have state evaluation function which returns appropriately sized vectors

Comment: @krokodil nesreka's suggestion seems appropriate then.

Comment: @eponier @nesreka Removing `(n:nat)` parameter will make vector expressions untyped and I will not be able to enforce vector's dimensionality. Of course, if nothing else works I will go this way, but that would mean I will need to check/and prove separately if dimensions match.

Comment: @krokodil The proposition is to turn the parameter into an index (`VExpr : nat -> Type`), not to remove it.

Comment: turning it into an index worked! I will be glad to accept this as an answer if you post it as such! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the second inductive so that it uses an index instead of a parameter.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Inductive NExpr: Type :=
| NVarValue: nat -> NExpr
| NConst: nat -> NExpr
| NPlus : NExpr -> NExpr -> NExpr
| NMinus: NExpr -> NExpr -> NExpr
| NNth  : forall n, VExpr n -> NExpr -> NExpr
with
VExpr : nat -> Type :=
| VVarValue: forall n, nat -> VExpr n
| VConst: forall n, Vector.t nat n -> VExpr n.
```